# Android pass OnClick Event to underlying View in FrameLayout

Tags: android, onclick, android-framelayout

Idea: I want to display an image as background. On this image, somewhere on the screen there is a little clickable View. On top of this all, a black draggabke image with a little transparent whole (displaying the underlying Views).

This is solved with a FrameLayout, whereas the image is the first frame, the View is the second frame and the ''Viewport'' is the third frame.

Now the goal is, that the user can click that second frame, if it is visible in the viewport. The problem is, that this transparency is only ''in the png'', not in the frame itself. So the solution would be to propagate the OnClick coordinates to the underlying frame. How is this possible? Is there a functionality for a FrameLayout in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Making the upper layer as clickable false, i think the click event should be ignored by it and passed to the second frame

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom class that extends FrameLayout
2. Add the following overridden methods

```java
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  return false;
}

@Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

  return true;

}
```

3. Then add touch listener to frame layout like

```java
framelayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

  underLyingView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return false;
  }
});
```

4. This will pass onclick event to the view underLyingView which lies under FrameLayout